# How do I convert an AHK script to registry?

Tags: windows, keyboard, registry, autohotkey

I have this AHK script. How do I convert this into windows registry?

```
SetCapsLockState, alwaysoff
CapsLock & u::Send {Home}
CapsLock & o::Send {End}
CapsLock & i::Send {Up}
CapsLock & j::Send {Left}
CapsLock & k::Send {Down}
CapsLock & l::Send {Right}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set hotkeys like these in the registry, you can only remap individual keys. E.g. turn `Capslock` into another `Backspace` or `RShift`. Read [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#registry).